# UIImage.AsJPEG() returns "Cannot cast from source type to destination type."

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiimage, xamarin

I'm building an iOS App where I need to use the camera and save images from it into the App folder.

When I try to convert the image from the camera to a JPEG or PNG, I'm getting: "Cannot cast from source type to destination type."

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public class ImagePickerDelegate : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
{
    public ImagePickerDelegate()
    {
    }

    public override void FinishedPickingImage(UIImagePickerController picker, UIImage image, NSDictionary editingInfo)
    {
        var documentsDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string jpgFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsDirectory, string.Format("{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));

        using (NSData imageData = image.AsJPEG(0.2f))
        {
            NSError err;
            if (!imageData.Save(jpgFilename, false, out err))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Saving of file failed: " + err.Description);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs when I call:

```
 using (NSData imageData = image.AsJPEG(0.2f))
```

Any ideas?

Here is the Stacktrace:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage.AsJPEG () [0x00006] in    /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/.pmcs-compat.UIImage.cs:53
 at App.ImagePickerDelegate.FinishedPickingImage (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImagePickerController picker, MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage image, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary editingInfo) [0x00024] in     /Users/giusepecasagrande/Dropbox/SoftwareDev/AppName/AppName/AppName/ImagePickerDelegate.cs:37
 at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
 at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/.pmcs-compat.UIApplication.cs:38
 at BeBabby.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/giusepecasagrande/Dropbox/SoftwareDev/AppName/AppName/AppName/Main.cs:16
```

And here is a sample project that I created:
https://github.com/GiusepeCasagrande/XamarinSimpleCameraSample/tree/master

If you input this part of code in the Picker delegate, you can see the problem.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @jonathanpeppers, I just added the stack trace to the original question.

Comment: It looks like UIImageJPEGRepresentation is returning something which is not an NSData. Does this happen with any image, or just one in particular?

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge even when I use something like: var imageData = image.AsJPEG(0.2f) I still get the same error. And it happens to images tha I get from camera.

Comment: Your sample works fine for me, with the FinishedPickingImage code from above. Are you running this in the simulator or on a device (which device)?

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge I'm running on a device, an iPad2. For now I solved the problem by implementing FinishedPickingMedia instead and getting the image by: UIImage item = (UIImage)info.ObjectForKey(UIImagePickerController.OriginalImage);

Comment: @jonathanpeppers Totally OT, but I must ask: is this coincidence? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/111612273/hmmmm.png :-)

Comment: @Krumelur haha! Totally. I took that picture the day I was unboxing my stuff after moving and I had just found my old pipe. Funny coincidence. :)

Comment: The sample linked to is not the same one that is being discussed here, it lacks the above code.

Comment: @miguel.de.icaza I know, I was avoiding to add this peace of code until it was working. 
Now its updated, and I honestly don't know how,  but it's working.

Comment: Seems to me that the same code that was crashing, I pasted here, then copied back to project and now its working. Magic? :)
I'm now sure what happened, but what I know is: the project is now running and working flawless.

Thanks you all for your efforts and help.

Comment: @Krumelur I think Giusepe stole my pipe! I can't find it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering this thread, since the problem seems to be solved somehow. And the sample project is now working.

Pasting the comment I made earlier:

Seems to me that the same code that was crashing, I pasted here, then copied back to project and now its working.

Magic? :)

I'm now sure what happened, but what I know is: the project is now running and working flawless. Thanks you all for your efforts and help.

Comment: Having the same issue. It seems to be something intermittent and hard to track down. There is an bug report here https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=16269

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried overriding the method FinidPickingMedia instead of Finishpickingimage ?

Comment: Yes, I ended overriding both of them, and seems that the FinidPickingMedia is always called. I mean, should it be called only when using the library?